# How to separate php array result

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem where I am coding a server status for my game server. It works fine, but there is one problem… The array output is in one line like this:

```
Array ( [online] => 1 [error] => [hostname] => chromaville.com [port] => 25565 [version] => 1.12 [software] => CraftBukkit on Bukkit 1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT [game_type] => SMP [game_name] => MINECRAFT [players] => 0 [max_players] => 1000 [player_list] => )
```

instead of a list like so:

```
Array (
    [online] => 1 
    [error] => 
    [hostname] => chromaville.com 
    [port] => 25565 [version] => 1.12 
    [software] => CraftBukkit on Bukkit 1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT 
    [game_type] => SMP 
    [game_name] => MINECRAFT 
    [players] => 0 
    [max_players] => 1000 
    [player_list] => 
);
```

Is it possible to somehow do it like this? Thank you! (Sorry if my spelling is bad, I haven’t slept in a long time and its 5:19 am currently…)
Here’s my code:

`index.php`:

```php
<?php
    require 'MCQuery.php';
    $status = new MCQuery();
    $array = ($status->GetStatus( 'chromaville.com', 25565 )-Response() );  
    print_r($array)
?>
```

`mcquery.php`:

```php
<?php
    class MCQuery
    {
        const STATISTIC = 0x00;
        const HANDSHAKE = 0x09;
        
        private $Socket;
        private $error;
        private $host;
        private $Info;
        private $Players;
        
        //public methods
        
        public function __construct()
        {
        }
        
        public function GetStatus($Host='127.0.0.1', $Port=25565, $Timeout=2)
        {
            $this->Clear();
            
            $this->host=$Host;
            
            if( !is_int( $Timeout ) || $Timeout < 0 )
            {
                $this->error="Invalid timeout";
                return $this;
            }
            
            $this->Socket = @fsockopen( 'udp://' . $Host, (int)$Port, $ErrNo, $ErrStr, $Timeout );
            
            if( $ErrNo || $this->Socket === false )
            {
                $this->error="Socket error";
                return $this;
            }
            
            @stream_set_timeout( $this->Socket, $Timeout );
            @stream_set_blocking( $this->Socket, true );
            
            $this->Query();
            
            @fclose( $this->Socket );
            
            return $this;
        }
        
        public function Response()
        {
            return array(
                'online'=>$this->error==null?true:false,
                'error'=>$this->error,
                'hostname'=>$this->host,
                'port'=>isset($this->Info['HostPort'])?$this->Info['HostPort']:null,
                'version'=>isset($this->Info['Version'])?$this->Info['Version']:null,
                'software'=>isset($this->Info['Software'])?$this->Info['Software']:null,
                'game_type'=>isset($this->Info['GameType'])?$this->Info['GameType']:null,
                'game_name'=>isset($this->Info['GameName'])?$this->Info['GameName']:null,
                'players'=>isset($this->Info['Players'])?$this->Info['Players']:null,
                'max_players'=>isset($this->Info['MaxPlayers'])?$this->Info['MaxPlayers']:null,
                'player_list'=>isset($this->Players)?$this->Players:null,
            );
        }
        
        
        //private methods
        
        private function Clear()
        {
            $this->Socket=null;
            $this->error=null;
            $this->host=null;
            $this->Info=null;
            $this->Players=null;
        }
        
        private function Query()
        {
            //challenge
            $Data = $this->WriteData( self :: HANDSHAKE );
            if( $Data === false )
            {
                $this->error="Failed to receive challenge";
            }
            $challenge=pack( 'N', $Data );
            
            
            $Data = $this->WriteData( self :: STATISTIC, $challenge . pack( 'c*', 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 ) );
            
            if( !$Data )
            {
                $this->error="Failed to receive status";
            }
            
            $Last = '';
            $Info = Array( );
            
            $Data    = substr( $Data, 11 ); // splitnum + 2 int
            $Data    = explode( "\x00\x00\x01player_\x00\x00", $Data );
            
            if( count( $Data ) !== 2 )
            {
                $this->error="Failed to parse server's response";
            }
            
            $Players = @substr( $Data[ 1 ], 0, -2 );
            $Data    = explode( "\x00", $Data[ 0 ] );
            
            // Array with known keys in order to validate the result
            // It can happen that server sends custom strings containing bad things (who can know!)
            $Keys = Array(
                'hostname'   => 'HostName',
                'gametype'   => 'GameType',
                'version'    => 'Version',
                'plugins'    => 'Plugins',
                'map'        => 'Map',
                'numplayers' => 'Players',
                'maxplayers' => 'MaxPlayers',
                'hostport'   => 'HostPort',
                'hostip'     => 'HostIp',
                'game_id'    => 'GameName'
            );
            
            foreach( $Data as $Key => $Value )
            {
                if( ~$Key & 1 )
                {
                    if( !array_key_exists( $Value, $Keys ) )
                    {
                        $Last = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                    $Last = $Keys[ $Value ];
                    $Info[ $Last ] = '';
                }
                else if( $Last != false )
                {
                    $Info[ $Last ] = $Value;
                }
            }
            
            // Ints
            $Info[ 'Players' ]    = $this->error==null?@intval( $Info[ 'Players' ] ):null;
            $Info[ 'MaxPlayers' ] = $this->error==null?@intval( $Info[ 'MaxPlayers' ] ):null;
            $Info[ 'HostPort' ]   = $this->error==null?@intval( $Info[ 'HostPort' ] ):null;
            
            // Parse "plugins", if any
            if( @$Info[ 'Plugins' ] )
            {
                $Data = explode( ": ", $Info[ 'Plugins' ], 2 );
                
                $Info[ 'RawPlugins' ] = $Info[ 'Plugins' ];
                $Info[ 'Software' ]   = $Data[ 0 ];
                
                if( count( $Data ) == 2 )
                {
                    $Info[ 'Plugins' ] = explode( "; ", $Data[ 1 ] );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $Info[ 'Software' ] = $this->error==null?'Vanilla':null;
            }
            
            $this->Info = $Info;
            
            if( $Players )
            {
                $this->Players = explode( "\x00", $Players );
            }
        }
        
        private function WriteData( $Command, $Append = "" )
        {
            $Command = pack( 'c*', 0xFE, 0xFD, $Command, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 ) . $Append;
            $Length  = strlen( $Command );
            
            if( $Length !== @fwrite( $this->Socket, $Command, $Length ) )
            {
                $this->error="Failed to write on socket";
            }
            
            $Data = @fread( $this->Socket, 4096 );
            
            if( $Data === false )
            {
                $this->error="Failed to read from socket";
            }
            
            if( strlen( $Data ) < 5 || $Data[ 0 ] != $Command[ 2 ] )
            {
                $this->error="Strlen error";
            }
            
            return substr( $Data, 5 );
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Don't use `print_r` for outputting, use it for debugging. Iterate over the array and output it as you want. `foreach` is a good place to start.

Comment: Agreed with @user3783243

Answer (score 0):

use `echo "<pre>";` before your `print_r` function. Like as below:

```
<?php
    require 'MCQuery.php';  

    $status = new MCQuery();

    $array = ($status->GetStatus( 'chromaville.com', 25565 )->Response() );  
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array)
 ?>
```

> I think you were trying to debug your code, not trying to display production result by print_r

Comment: Nope, dosn't work... Have a look for yourself... chromaville.com/index.php

Comment: @Major of course I did. If you want to debug any array and want to show more human readable way you can easily do that by `echo "<pre>";` You just need to check your data returning as array or something else. just debug it by `var_dump($array);`

Comment: Also you have error in your code, you should call `Response()` with `->` not just `-`. plz check my ans. Thanks